# Why is the FileContent zero bytes on all Attachment objects except the first one?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one form through which ,Sender text his email-id and password and selects attachment

using fileupload,recipients's email id  i am getting from database table,email is reaching to recipients fine..but

problem is that when i attach a attachment ,attachment's size goes 0 except 1st email-id

,which i am getting from table....i have pasted code..

```
foreach (string email_to in list_emails)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(email_to);
    mail.Subject = "UPDATES FROM ATTENDANCE S/W";
    mail.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text.ToString());
    mail.Body = txtMessage.Text;
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        Attachment myAttachment =
                           new Attachment(FileUpload1.FileContent, fileName);
        mail.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
    }
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtFrom.Text.ToString(), txtPasswd.Text.ToString());
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `FileContent` is a `Stream` and so when you read from it the position of that `Stream` is left at the end. Consider something like this. At the top of the loop store the bytes, you don't need to keep reading them from the `Stream` anyway:

```
bool hasFile = FileUpload1.HasFile;

int fileLen = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
Stream stream = FileUpload1.FileContent;

byte[] file = new byte[fileLen];
stream.Read(file, 0, fileLen);
```

and then down in the loop, leverage the variable:

```
new Attachment(new MemoryStream(file) ...
```

and you'll want to change the `if` statement to leverage the `bool`:

```
if (hasFile)
```

Comment: Michael Perrenoudcan not convert type System.IO.Stream to byte...Error

Comment: @user2053138, that should be a little better.

Comment: Michael Perrenoud  in read function and new attachment line it is giving error like invalid arguments

Comment: @user2053138, okay, I've edited the post to match the MSDN example a bit more. Most of those additional operations seem excessive - but that's how the example is written - so there could be some reasons behind it. Please keep in mind I'm not building this solution in Visual Studio - it's not feasible for me to rebuild your application - I'm just doing the best I can to lead you down the path.

Comment: Michael Perrenoudnow only this error  Attachment myAttachment =
                                           new Attachment(file,fileName);

Comment: @user2053138, what is the error? Giving me the line doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: argument is invalid it wants 1st arg as Stream

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26721/discussion-between-user2053138-and-michael-perrenoud)